# Having issues with Javascript dice game

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get one button to fire two functions. It's a basic dice based game: the player die on top works fine, but the computer die doesn't give a value.

```js
function Welcome()
{
        alert("Welcome " + document.getElementById("fname").value + "!");
}
 
function oldEnough(age)
{
        if (age< 18)
        {alert("UNDER 18 LEAVE NOW");
        }
}
 
//player dice roll//
function rollDice() {
        var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
        var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        //random number between 1 and 6(whole number)//
        var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
        //shows the random number value//
       
        die1.innerHTML = d1;
        die2.innerHTML = d2;
        status.innerHTML = "You Rolled "+diceTotal+".";
        if (d1 == d2){
                status.innerHTML +=" Doubles! Roll Again ";
        }
}
 
//computer dice roll//
function compDice() {
                var die3 = document.getElementById("die3")
                var die4 = document.getElementById("die4")
                var status2 = document.getElementById("status2")
               
                var d3 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6) +1;
                var d4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;
                var diceTotal = d3 + d4;
               
                die3.innerHTML = d3;
                die4.innerHTML = d4;
                status2.innerHTML = "Computer Rolled "+diceTotal+".";
}
```

```css
div.dice{
        float:left;
        width:32px:
        background:#D6D6D6;
        border:#999 1px solid;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:24px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:5px;
}
 
 
div.die{
        float:left;
        width:32px:
        background:#D6D6D6;
        border:#999 1px solid;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:24px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
<p>
Player Name:
<input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" onblur="Welcome()" />
</p>
 
Age:
<input id="age" name="age" id="age" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" onBlur="oldEnough(this.value)"/>
</p>
 
<div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
<div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
<button onclick="rollDice()";"compDice()">Roll Dice</button>
<h2 id="status" style="clear:left;"></h2>
 
 
 
<div id="die3" class="die">0</div>
<div id="die4" class="die">0</div>
<h2 id="status2" style="clear:right;"></h2>
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant code here. Just so you know, there's the snippets functionality for code.

Comment: Yeah, try not to make people leave this site in order to help you.

Comment: The problem is with your button onclick code. It should be `onclick="rollDice();compDice();"`, not `onclick="rollDice()";"compDice()"`.

Comment: Thanks for the, help. Will do from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<button onclick="rollDice()";"compDice()">Roll Dice</button>
```

to:

```
<button onclick="rollDice();compDice()">Roll Dice</button>
```